# Overriding PHP namespace for a specific class

Tags: php, namespaces

If I have a PHP namespace as follows:

```
<?php

   namespace A\B;

   $test = new MyClass();
```

it seems every time I create a new instance of class, the name is prefixed with the namespace, e.g.

```
$test = new A\B\MyClass();
```

What happens if I don't want to use a namespace for another class, e.g. I want to call

```
$test = C\D\AnotherClass();
```

Currently this becomes:

```
$test = A\B\C\D\AnotherClass();
```

which results in an error.

Comment: You'd add a leading \ to the class. e.g. `$test = new \C\D\AnotherClass()`

Comment: OR you could make use of the `use` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

For php7 you can wrap code in a namespace then call it with use in the global namespace declared using namespace with no name per the example below.

```
namespace FRED\WILMA\BAMBAM {   
    const FW = 2;
    function fw() {
        echo "<br>fw<br>";
    }
 }  

 namespace BARNEY\BETTY { // Create Namespace and add function
     function bb() {
         echo "<br>bb<br>";
     }
 }

 namespace  { // use global namespace
     use FRED\WILMA\BAMBAM;
     use BARNEY\BETTY;
     BETTY\bb();
     BAMBAM\fw();
 }
```